# make sure image loads absolutely as soon as possible

Tags: html

What ways are there to prioritize an <img> to load as soon as possible, with highest priority.
I am using the image in the middle of a quite large html document and im trying to get it loaded asap and also prevent layout shifting.

1. i have added the attribute and value `loading="eager"`
2. i have compressed the image as much as possible
3. i have added `fetchpriority="high"`
4. i have set the height and width
5. brotli enabled on server

Would i be able to load it first in the <head> tag some how? i know it will not be used there obviously, but it is higher up in the code? would it be downloaded and parsed before say, all external css, js and font files?

would loading it somehow via javascript be quicker?

is any of the ways above wrong? any other tricks?

Comment: You could [add the image data as base64 data in the image tag](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/html/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html.html). That way the image is loaded with the HTML. For easy use: https://www.base64-image.de

Comment: You can use *webp*. https://developers.google.com/speed/webp

Comment: yes, i forgot to mention i did try encoding it to bas64 earlier, but then i can not cache it for future page loads.

Comment: Ah, so it's a dynamically generated HTML page. Yes, you shouldn't cache those pages.

Comment: @Amini thank you for the suggestion, i have compared different formats, .webp .png .jpg and compressed as much as possible with freeconvert.com (settled on .png)

Comment: @KIKOSoftware yes the page itself is dynamic (pulling data from db via php), but the image is allowed to be cached so will set proper cache headers for it via either htaccess or php at later stage.

Comment: Are you using any frontend ssr framework?

Comment: If you set the image width and height, why do you still get layout shifts?

Comment: `<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://example.com">` and `<link rel="preconnect" href="https://example.com">`

Comment: Also make sure GZIP or brotli is enabled on your webserver

Comment: And for images you should use `<img src="..." srcset="...">` (mind `srcset`)

Comment: @Amini frontend ssr framework? what is that?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware layout shift, maybe i already solved that one. (not on the development machine at the moment) but still want to load the image faster faster faster :)))

Comment: @Pieterjan yes, brotli is enabled on the server by default by my host (thanks for suggesting it, i will add it to original post)

Comment: @Pieterjan preconnect and dns-prefetch is very good ideas. but currently the images are on the same domain as the html document so would not help(?). but if i  move it to a cdn, then yes. good one!

Comment: Well, there is a way to preload an image: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types/preload

Comment: @KIKOSoftware preload added! did not have that one.

Comment: Does preloading help?

Comment: yes , it made a big difference.